# Run WCF service getting error Failed to add a service. Service metadata may not be accessible

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf

I tried a WCF service which uploads files.

Below is the code:

restService.svc

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;

namespace restService
{
    // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the class name "restService" in code, svc and config file together.
    // NOTE: In order to launch WCF Test Client for testing this service, please select restService.svc or restService.svc.cs at the Solution Explorer and start debugging.
    public class restService : IrestService
    {
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "UploadFile?fileName={fileName}")]
        public string UploadFile(string fileName, Stream fileContents)
        {
            //save file
            try
            {
                string absFileName = string.Format("{0}\\FileUpload\\{1}"
                                        , AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory
                                        , fileName);
                using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(absFileName, FileMode.Create))
                {
                    fileContents.CopyTo(fs);
                    fileContents.Close();
                }
                return "Upload OK";
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return "FAIL ==> " + ex.Message;
            }


        }
    }
}
```

IrestService.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Web; 
using System.Text;
using System.IO; 


namespace restService
{
    // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the interface name "IrestService" in both code and config file together.
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IrestService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        string UploadFile(string fileName, Stream fileContents);


    }
}
```

web.config

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <configuration>

      <appSettings>
        <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
      </appSettings>
      <system.web>
        <compilation targetFramework="4.5" />
        <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
      </system.web>
      <system.serviceModel>



    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>

          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>

          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>



    <protocolMapping>
        <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>    
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

When I use WCF test client to test the service, I got the error:

> Failed to add a service. Service metadata may not be accessible. Make
>   sure your service is running and exposing metadata.
>
> Error: Cannot obtain Metadata from
>   http://localhost:49202/restService.svc If this is a Windows (R)
>   Communication Foundation service to which you have access, please
>   check that you have enabled metadata publishing at the specified
>   address. For help enabling metadata publishing, please refer to the
>   MSDN documentation at
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=65455.WS-Metadata Exchange
>   Error URI: http://localhost:49202/restService.svc Metadata contains a
>   reference that cannot be resolved:
>   'http://localhost:49202/restService.svc'. The requested service,
>   'http://localhost:49202/restService.svc' could not be activated. See
>   the server's diagnostic trace logs for more information.HTTP GET Error
>   URI: http://localhost:49202/restService.svc There was an error
>   downloading 'http://localhost:49202/restService.svc'. The request
>   failed with the error message:--  Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> For request in operation UploadFile to be a stream the operation must
>   have a single parameter whose type is Stream.  Description: An
>   unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web
>   request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the
>   error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: For request in
>   operation UploadFile to be a stream the operation must have a single
>   parameter whose type is Stream.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [InvalidOperationException: For request in operation UploadFile to be
>   a stream the operation must have a single parameter whose type is
>   Stream.]
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.StreamFormatter.ValidateAndGetStreamPart(MessageDescription
>   messageDescription, Boolean isRequest, String operationName) +12750641
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.OperationFormatter..ctor(OperationDescription
>   description, Boolean isRpc, Boolean isEncoded) +457
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DataContractSerializerOperationFormatter..ctor(OperationDescription
>   description, DataContractFormatAttribute dataContractFormatAttribute,
>   DataContractSerializerOperationBehavior serializerFactory) +58
>   System.ServiceModel.Description.DataContractSerializerOperationBehavior.GetFormatter(OperationDescription
>   operation, Boolean& formatRequest, Boolean& formatReply, Boolean
>   isProxy) +217
>   System.ServiceModel.Description.DataContractSerializerOperationBehavior.System.ServiceModel.Description.IOperationBehavior.ApplyDispatchBehavior(OperationDescription
>   description, DispatchOperation dispatch) +58
>   System.ServiceModel.Description.DispatcherBuilder.BindOperations(ContractDescription
>   contract, ClientRuntime proxy, DispatchRuntime dispatch) +250
>   System.ServiceModel.Description.DispatcherBuilder.InitializeServiceHost(ServiceDescription
>   description, ServiceHostBase serviceHost) +3171
>   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.InitializeRuntime() +65
>   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.OnBeginOpen() +34
>   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout) +49
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan
>   timeout) +308
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open() +36
>   System.ServiceModel.HostingManager.ActivateService(ServiceActivationInfo
>   serviceActivationInfo, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity) +90
>   System.ServiceModel.HostingManager.EnsureServiceAvailable(String
>   normalizedVirtualPath, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity)
>   +598[ServiceActivationException: The service '/restService.svc' cannot be activated due to an exception during compilation.  The exception
>   message is: For request in operation UploadFile to be a stream the
>   operation must have a single parameter whose type is Stream..]
>   System.Runtime.AsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result) +485044
>   System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult
>   result) +174
>   System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHttpHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult
>   result) +6
>   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.OnAsyncHandlerCompletion(IAsyncResult
>   ar) +129

I would like to know what is going wrong with my code?

Comment: Did you *read* the error message: **"For request in operation UploadFile to be a stream the operation must have a single parameter whose type is Stream"**.  Your method has two parameters:  `string UploadFile(string fileName, Stream fileContents);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to MSDN https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733742(v=vs.110).aspx

> The programming model for streaming is straightforward. For receiving streamed data, specify an operation contract that has a single Stream typed input parameter. For returning streamed data, return a Stream reference.

When streaming, you cannot have additional parameters in your methods.  Having an additional fileName parameter is causing the exception.

You may be able to use a message contract to accomplish the same thing and pass additional fields as properties of a class, as long as only one property is a Stream.

```
[MessageContract]
public class UploadStreamMessage
{
   [MessageHeader]
   public string fileName;
   [MessageBodyMember]
   public Stream fileContents;
}
```